# Cannot open excel file generated by django

Tags: python, django, excel, pandas

Say there's a dataframe from pandas like :

```
                          mediabuy      cpa        mediabuy        cpc          
cost        2020-02         0.00       371929.95   15956581.16    16328511.11
            2020-04        1311.92     224747.07   26710431.81    26936490.80
total                      1311.92     596677.02   42667012.97     43265001.91
```

I want to create an excel file in django, and I've tried with codes as below:

```py
# return excel view


            df = pd.DataFrame(data, index=index, columns=column)

            # saved as excel
            excel_writer = pd.ExcelWriter(path='temp.xlsx', engine='openpyxl')
            df.to_excel(excel_writer)
            wb = excel_writer.book

            response = HttpResponse(save_virtual_workbook(wb))
            response["Content-Type"] = 'application/vnd.ms-excel'
            response['Content-Disposition'] = 'attachment; filename={}.xlsx'.format("data"))
            return response
```

I'm working with `python3.6.8`, `django2.2.4`, `pandas1.0.3`, `openpyxl3.0.3`

But I always get an error saying "excel file cannot opened because the file format or file extension is not valid".

Why am I getting this error?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unless there is a problem with the structure of the data in the dataframe you should be able to achieve this using:

```
from io import BytesIO

df = pd.DataFrame(data, index=index, columns=column)

stream_file = BytesIO()
df.to_excel(stream_file)
stream_file.seek(0)

response = HttpResponse(stream_file)
response["Content-Type"] = 'application/vnd.ms-excel'
response['Content-Disposition'] = 'attachment; filename={}.xlsx'.format("data")
return response
```

Comment: In that case, you might want to try `df = df.reset_index()` prior to `df.to_excel(stream_file)` as it could be related to the dataframe being grouped.

If you add the print out of `df.to_dict('records')` to your question it'll be easier to reproduce

Answer (score 0):

Chunking the Data always helps. Or you can create a background task with celery

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/35526161)